# filter with react state not filtering values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am stumped here and no idea why as I have filtered react state many times before but this time it is doing something unexpected.

I have a functional component that has an input. The input has an `onChange` event. The on change event sends `e` to a function called `updateSocial`. This function takes the param e, more specifically, `e.target.name`, and `e.target.value`, and creates an object to store in state. `{inputType: e.target.name, value: e.target.value}`.

The state, `bandSocials` is an array of these objects... If the user edits the field, the function should filter out the old value, and replace it with the new value.

Heres my code:

```
  const updateSocial = (e) => {
    //Turn the bandSocials state into a new array so that I don't change the existing state yet.
    let socialsArray = Array.from(bandSocials)

    //Define the input type and the value.
    let inputType = e.target.name
    let value = e.target.value

    //Filter out the old value- This is where it is not working.
    socialsArray.filter((s) => s.inputType !== inputType);

    //Add in the new value
    socialsArray.push({inputType, value})

    //Replace the bandSocails with the new array.
    setSocials((band) => {
      return {
        ...band,
        bandSocials : socialsArray,
      };
    });
  };
```

Each time the `onChange` event is called, it adds another object and does not filter out the old object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `push`, which modifies the array, `filter` creates a new array and returns it.

```
let filteredArray = socialsArray.filter( ... )
```